# Kotlin `typealias` feature

Tags: keyword, kotlin, type-alias

According to the source of [Kotlin's lexer](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/lexer/KtTokens.java), there is a `typealias` keyword, and it's not "reserved for future use" like `yield` and `typeof`.

Also, the [grammar reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#memberDeclaration) suggests that `typealias` should be a valid keyword for a class member declaration, and when I type `typealias` in IntelliJ IDEA (Android Studio) with Kotlin plugin it recognizes it as a keyword but I get ***expecting member declaration*** error. I have also tried using it  with the "usual" syntax, for example like it is implemented in Swift, however with no success.

So, is the `typealias` feature actually implemented in Kotlin (as of 1.0), and if so, what is the syntax for it? Is there any documentation that describes its use?

---

### Update

**Kotlin 1.1 supporting [type aliases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html) is now out!**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a `typealias`, you can provide an alternative name for an existing type since Kotlin 1.1:

```
typealias Multimap<K, V> = MutableMap<K, MutableList<V>>
```

For more information, see [the official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html) or the [KEEP proposal](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/type-aliases.md).

Comment: Kotlin 1.1 Beta is out and it has typealiases: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/01/kotlin-1-1-beta-is-here/